# Azure AD B2C Custom Policies - Javascript

Tags: azure, policy, azure-ad-b2c

Can we add javascript inside custom policies and can we use button click function to redirect to another page?

I have referred the [following links](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview) when implementing custom policies.

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript is now supported for custom policies. Here is the official documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-samples

**NB:** it seems you need to use the **b2clogin.com** domain (not login.microsoftonline.com). I cannot find this documented at the moment, but a quick test shows that JavaScript is stripped out on login.microsoftonline.com. Here is the documentation for using b2clogin.com: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/b2clogin.

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript is currently not supported in custom UI. See the note under [Create your HTML5 content](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-ui-customization-custom#create-your-html5-content).

Answer (score 0):

Custom JavaScript is not currently supported in Azure AD B2C. We are working to enable that feature - please vote for the feature [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/15493536-add-support-for-javascript-inside-the-custom-ui-br) so that you can get an update when the preview is available.

Comment: how come it is used in this sample then? https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/tree/master/wingtipgamesb2c/Templates

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can use JavaScript in [custom policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-overview-custom).  See this sample: [active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies.](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-b2c-advanced-policies/tree/master/wingtipgamesb2c/Templates)

**PlayerProfileUpdate.html**

```
<script src="https://wingtipb2ctmpls.blob.core.windows.net/wingtiptoys/js/analytics.js" />
<script src="https://wingtipb2ctmpls.blob.core.windows.net/wingtiptoys/js/selfasserted-playerprofileupdate.js"></script>
```

I don't know for sure about the button click redirect.  On the surface, if you can use JavaScript then you should be able to do this.